# Replace href value once the popup appears from the third party script is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to replace the href value by placing the below code at the bottom of the jsp after the third party script is placed but href value is not getting replaced as the popup takes time to get displayed

```
(function () {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = 'third party url using which we get the popup';
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
})();
```

> Placing the below code to replace href of the popup

```
$('#pid a').attr("href",'javascript:void(0)');
```

Comment: Can you please add a sample code that how and when you are replacing href value ?

Comment: @Hemal edited as suggested

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are calling your function on page load directly. Can you please try with the $(document).ready(). Below is the sample code.

```
$(document).ready(
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.async = true;
  s.src = 'third party url using which we get the popup';
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
);
```